# Complete an incomplete dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

Good morning.

I have a dataframe that can be both like this:

```
df1 = 
    zone   date     p1   p2
0      A      1    154    2
1      B      1   2647    7
2      C      1      0    0
3      A      2   1280    3
4      B      2   6809   20
5      C      2    288    5
6      A      3   2000    4
```

and like this:

```
df2 = 
    zone   date     p1   p2
0      A      1    154    2
1      B      1   2647    7
2      C      1      0    0
3      A      2   1280    3
4      B      2   6809   20
5      C      2    288    5
```

The difference between the two is only that the case may arise in which one, or several but not all, zones do have data for the highest of the time periods (column date). My desired result is to be able to complete the dataframe until a certain period of time (3 in the example), in the following way in each of the cases:

```
df1_result = 
    zone   date     p1   p2
0      A      1    154    2
1      B      1   2647    7
2      C      1      0    0
3      A      2   1280    3
4      B      2   6809   20
5      C      2    288    5
6      A      3   2000    4
7      B      3   6809   20
8      C      3    288    5

df2_result = 
    zone   date     p1   p2
0      A      1    154    2
1      B      1   2647    7
2      C      1      0    0
3      A      2   1280    3
4      B      2   6809   20
5      C      2    288    5
6      A      3   1280    3
7      B      3   6809   20
8      C      3    288    5
```

I've tried different combinations of pivot and fillna with different methods, but I can't achieve the previous result.

I hope my explanation was understood.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reindex` to create entries for all dates in the range, and then forward fill the last value into it.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1,154, 2],
                    ['B', 1,2647, 7],
                    ['C', 1,0, 0],
                    ['A', 2,1280, 3],
                    ['B', 2,6809, 20],
                    ['C', 2,288, 5],
                    ['A', 3,2000, 4]], 
                   columns=['zone', 'date', 'p1', 'p2'])

result = df1.groupby("zone").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("date").reindex(range(1, 4), method='ffill'))

print(result)
```

To get

```
          zone    p1  p2
zone date               
A    1       A   154   2
     2       A  1280   3
     3       A  2000   4
B    1       B  2647   7
     2       B  6809  20
     3       B  6809  20
C    1       C     0   0
     2       C   288   5
     3       C   288   5
```

Comment: Won't yield necessarily the expected output, I think (unless df is always sorted)

Comment: @RafaelC The reindex should set the index to the same order as the given index, so should be sorted in this case. Can remove the `method` parameter from `reindex`, and add a`sort_index().ffill()` after if not.

Comment: Yes, df is always sorted, however, i've the following problem: in column zone I just showed an example, but in my code, this column is filled with names of real zones of my country, so when I execute your code I get an `UnicodeDecideError`. I don't understand why that happens, due to I manipulate this type of dataframes and I obtain no errors.

Comment: @Á.Garzón Are you reading this file from a CSV or something? What encoding are you reading with? Can you try with the parameter `encoding='utf-8-sig'` or `encoding='utf-8'` to `read_csv`?

Comment: Data are read from a postgresql DB. Where should I put in my code these parameters?

Comment: Have you got a sample of how you read the data? Sounds like your data is not in Unicode, would need to be sure to read your data in whatever encoding it is in.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can reconstruct a `pd.MultiIndex` from your original `df` and use `fillna` to get the `max` from each subgroup of `zone` you have.

first, build your index

```
ind    = df1.set_index(['zone', 'date']).index
levels = ind.levels
n      = len(levels[0])
labels = [np.tile(np.arange(n), n), np.repeat(np.arange(0, n), n)]
```

Then, use `pd.MultiIndex` constructor to `reindex`

```
df1.set_index(['zone', 'date'])\
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex(levels= levels, labels= labels))\
   .fillna(df1.groupby(['zone']).max())

            p1      p2
zone    date        
A       1   154.0   2.0
B       1   2647.0  7.0
C       1   0.0     0.0
A       2   1280.0  3.0
B       2   6809.0  20.0
C       2   288.0   5.0
A       3   2000.0  4.0
B       3   6809.0  20.0
C       3   288.0   5.0
```

To fill `df2`, just change from `df1` in this last line of code to `df2` and you get

```
            p1      p2
zone    date        
A       1   154.0   2.0
B       1   2647.0  7.0
C       1   0.0     0.0
A       2   1280.0  3.0
B       2   6809.0  20.0
C       2   288.0   5.0
A       3   2000.0  4.0
B       3   6809.0  20.0
C       3   288.0   5.0
```

I suggest not to copy/paste directly the code and try to run, but rather try to understand the process and make slight changes if needed depending on how different your original data frame is from what you posted.

Comment: Just testing the first line of your solution gives me `NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time`

Comment: @Á.Garzón wow, which version of python and pandas are you using ?

Comment: python 2.7 and pandas 0.23.4